# How can I receive files via Bluetooth without first requesting to receive them?

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have found that to receive files on my PC, I must *first* right-click the Bluetooth icon in the taskbar and select "Receive a file".
[image: Windows 10 receive Bluetooth file manually]
Then I can send the files from the phone by selecting `Share > Bluetooth > [PC Name], and they will begin to transfer.

If I try to send a file from phone to PC without first choosing to receive a file on the PC, the phone quickly shows that the transfer was unsuccessful

Is there any way for me to either:

1. Send files from a phone and have them automatically received without confirmation on the PC?
2. Send files from a phone and then accept to receive them on the PC
   afterward?

I know that with my previous PCs, I could simply send files from any of my Android phones by selecting `Share > Bluetooth > [PC Name]` and at then the PC would show a dialog asking if I want to receive the file(s). After confirming, the transfer would begin. I don't fully grasp what made them different, as I didn't personally install anything bluetooth related on them.

Comment: The simplest solution is to send the files via email to yourself.

Comment: @harrymc - Perhaps, but email is not always possible due to lack of a network connection. Plus many email services block certain file types and sizes, adding even more extra steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking what has changed, then Windows itself has changed,
to protect you against unwanted files.
Microsoft has now published the procedure they impose in the article
[Share files over Bluetooth](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026874/windows-10-share-files-over-bluetooth), which is exactly as you have observed.

Should you wish to avoid this procedure, your options are to either use email
or a third-party application.

Examples of such applications are
[Join](https://joaoapps.com/join/)
(free) or
[Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)
(limited free account).

Another possibility is to install on the phone an application for an SSH
server, for example on Android the SSHDroid, then use for example WinSCP
on the PC to directly access the folder on the phone from the PC.

Comment: Was this change implemented in Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, it happened after one of the major updates. I don't know exactly when, since I don't transfer files that often. I thought also of another option which I added.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - It seems this was a recent change.

Comment: Damn. All they had to do was automatically allow incoming files from previously paired devices or create some other "trusted devices" list. They remove features for security reasons and forget to consider the decreased usability :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make a keyboard shortcut (either via Explorer, or better, using AutoHotKey or similar) to the following command:

```
fsquirt -receive
```

This does not solve the problem entirely but alleviates some of the pain of receiving files via Bluetooth without requiring any 3rd-party software.